# Merging multiple awk commands while retaining functionality

Tags: bash, linux, awk

Turned in a project a few days ago, and I needed a way to filter and format values off a file. I decided to go for a bash script since it seemed like a good option, and I came up with the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

amount=100

awk '{
    if($i == "data: 1"){
        getline;
        getline;
        print $2}}' sensordata.txt > temp1.txt
awk -v m=$amount 'NR<=m' temp1.txt > temp12.txt
maxval1=$(awk -v val=0 '{
    if($i>val) 
        val=$i;};
    END {print val}' temp12.txt)
minval1=$(awk -v val=1024 '{
    if($i<val) 
        val=$i;};
    END {print val}' temp12.txt)
awk -v max=$maxval1 -v min=$minval1 '{
    if($i!=max && $i!=min)
        print $0}' temp12.txt > data1.txt
avgval1=$(awk -v avg=0 '{
    avg+=$i;};
    END {
        avg/=NR;
        print avg}' data1.txt)
rm temp1.txt
rm temp12.txt
```

This is used 3 times for different files as I need to filter it 3 times.

The original file contains several values I need to filter, all of which have a "title" ("data: 1"), and all lines are separated by a "---". It'd look something like this:

```
data: 1
<--->
data: 111
<--->
data: 2
<--->
data: 222
```

and so on.

My script copies all values 2 lines below the "title" into another file, moves a certain amount of lines to another file, finds the maximum and minimum value, then moves all values different to max and min to a last file, from which the average of all values is calculated. Then it's graphed using GNUPLOT.

I was wondering if there was a better way of achieving this, as I quite clearly abused the AWK command, and everything seems quite messy from my perspective, specially because I'm constantly moving values from the original file into a new one.

Comment: This sort of question demands an exact output that you would like to produce for the given sample input. And Yes, all your `awk` commands can be simplified into one.

Comment: (While I think this should work, it sure *looks* like it shouldn't.)